# How to set parameter and its value to HREF dynamic using javascript

Tags: html, hyperlink, attributes, href

I have a link like following

```
<a id="dynamicLink" href="http://www.w3schools.com?userName=test">Visit W3Schools</a>
```

I would like to change the value of `userName` from `test` to `test1`.

How to do that using javascript?

could someone help me on this?

Comment: May i know the reason why i got down vote ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using a library to work with `URI`s. It will provide some consistency. Here is an example using [URI.js](http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/):

```js
// Get our <a> element
var l = document.getElementById('dynamicLink');

// Use URI.js to work with the URI
// http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/
var uri = URI(l.href);

// Get the query string as an object
var qs = uri.query(true);

// Change our value
qs.userName = 'test1'

// Update the URI object
uri.query(qs);

// Set our new HREF on the <a> element
l.href = uri;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/URI.js/1.15.2/URI.min.js"></script>

<a id="dynamicLink" href="http://www.w3schools.com?userName=test&someOtherKey=val">Visit W3Schools</a>
```

Comment: Jon Surrell this is replacing the text but removes other parameter also if i pass the comma separated value then it creates multiple parameter for each value. Please suggest as how to proceed further.

Comment: @Tony I've changed the example to account for this. You can also refer to the [URI.js docs](http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/)

Comment: Thank you Jon and sorry to disturb you again, i sent comma separated value and it takes only the first value and does even set the other values.

Comment: Thank you Jon, i got that, it was array and converted to using toString() and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("dynamicLink").href.replace("userName", "test1");
```

This should change the *value* of *userName* in *href* to *test1*

Comment: Ahs N it is not setting the value, please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: You are right. I read the question wrong. I just edited the answer to do what you required. Please test it again.

Comment: No and it is not replacing the value still. Please check